# $.ajax 'GET' is not working properly

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, rest

I'm trying to access rest service using ajax.
If I'll paste this link on any web browser it will give a result like this:

```
{"SessionID":"a7f58a4a-f922-47c1-8351-d2035df4968c","SourceIP":"127.0.0.1","UserID":313}
```

(Link has changed for security)
https://thisisjustasample/Rest/Authenticate/Login?username=user&password=pass123&ip=127.0.0.1

But I found no luck to access the link using ajax:

A call from 'View' part:

```
getdata('https://thisisjustasample/Rest/Authenticate/Login?username=user&password=pass123&ip=127.0.0.1');
```

Function inside js file:

```
function getdata(url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data) {
                showtooltip(data);
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, error) {
            showtooltip(xhr.status + ': ' + error);
        }
    });
}
```

It always return a '0' status. And when I check my database, nothing has changed with the data. What is wrong with the code?

Comment: What do you see in `firebug`?

Comment: are you sure you're not doing a cross-domain request?

Comment: I'm not familiar with firebug, but I'll try to use it.

Comment: @ZathrusWriter It took me for sometime till I get what you mean. Yes, I'm making a cross domain request. And I found some source on how to solve it.

Comment: could you post link to the source, so we all can benefit from it?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/128478/Consuming-WCF-REST-Services-Using-jQuery-AJAX-Call this works great with local hosting, but still I can't make it work for live server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a feeling the problem is that you are specifying a content type of json when you shouldn't specify a contentType, and your params should be part of data.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://thisisjustasample/Rest/Authenticate/Login",
    type: 'GET',
    data: "username=user&password=pass123&ip=127.0.0.1",
    success: function (data) {
        if (data) {
            showtooltip(data);
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, error) {
        showtooltip(xhr.status + ': ' + error);
    }
});
```

Comment: If this javascript is running on a page from http:// **url1** /some.html and the ajax looks like url: "https:// **url2** /Rets..., does **url1** = **url2**?

Comment: You need to use fiddler or Firebug or something else to monitor the request and response. Otherwise you are coding blind. Also you need to know what a cross domain call means and if you are hitting it or not. I don't think that's your problem, but you need to be sure.

Comment: @ErikPhilips the answer is no. and that causes a cross domain request. good thing I found some source that explains on how to solve it. but thanks anyway.